# EF Core wrong join statement

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following model classes in EF Core 2.2

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public long? PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I have checked the relations with SSMS and they are fine.

But when I use

```
 dbContext.Posts.Include(p => p.User);
```

EF Core generates the following join statement

```
FROM Posts [p] 
LEFT JOIN Users [p.Users] ON [p].[Id] = [p.Users].[PostId]
```

I'm including User from Post and expect it to be as below

```
FROM Posts [p]   
LEFT JOIN Users [p.Users] ON [p].[UserId] = [p.Users].[Id]
```

What is wrong with models?

Assume that I want to save last `PostId` in User model.

Is there an attribute to tell ef core which property to use when joining models?

Comment: What is the relationship between Post and User?

Comment: If you mean by this `builder.HasOne("Models.Post", "Post").WithOne("User").HasForeignKey("Models.User", "PostId");`

Comment: and for user it is `builder.HasOne("Models.User").WithMany("Posts").HasForeignKey("UserId")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion on the other response it looks like you want a User to contain Posts, but then also have the User track a reference to the Latest post.  EF can map this, however you will probably need to be a bit explicit about the relationships.

For instance:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
    public virtual Post LatestPost { get; set; }
}

[Table("Posts")]
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostText { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

then a Configuration to ensure EF wires up the relationship between user and posts correctly:

```
// EF6
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Posts)
            .WithRequired(x => x.User)
            .Map(x=>x.MapKey("UserId"));
        HasOptional(x => x.LatestPost)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x=>x.MapKey("LatestPostId"));
    }
}

// EFCore
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Posts)
            .WithOne(x => x.User)
            .HasForeignKey("UserId");
        HasOne(x => x.LatestPost)
            .WithMany()
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasForeignKey("LatestPostId");
    }
}
```

You can accomplish this in the OnModelCreating event with the modelBuilder reference as well. Note here I am not declaring FK properties in my entities. This too is an option, but I generally recommend not declaring FKs to avoid reference vs. FK update issues.  I've named the LatestPost FK as LatestPostId just to reveal a bit more accurately what it is for. It could be mapped to a "PostId" if you so choose.

Now lets say I go to add a new post and I want to associate it to the user, and assign it as the LatestPost for that user:

```
using (var context = new SomethingDbContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Include(x => x.Posts).Include(x => x.LatestPost)
        .Single(x => x.UserId == 1);

    var newPost = new Post { PostText = "Test", User = user };
    user.Posts.Add(newPost);
    user.LatestPost = newPost;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can update the "latest" post reference by loading the user and setting the LatestPost reference to the desired post.

There is a risk with this structure however that you should consider. The issue is that there is no way to reliably enforce (at a data level) that the LatestPost reference in a User actually references a post associated to that user.  For instance, if I have a latest post pointing to a particular post, then I delete that post reference from the user's Posts collection, that can result in FK constraint errors, or simply disassociate the post from the user, but the user latest post still points at that record. I can also assign another user's post to this user's latest post reference. I.e.

```
using (var context = new SomethingDbContext())
{
    var user1 = context.Users.Include(x => x.Posts).Include(x => x.LatestPost)
        .Single(x => x.UserId == 1);
    var user1 = context.Users.Include(x => x.Posts).Include(x => x.LatestPost)
        .Single(x => x.UserId == 2);

    var newPost = new Post { PostText = "Test", User = user1 };
    user1.Posts.Add(newPost);
    user1.LatestPost = newPost;
    user2.LatestPost = newPost;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And that would be perfectly fine. User 2's "LatestPostId" would be set to this new post, even though this post's UserId only refers to User1.

A better solution when dealing with something like a Latest post is to *not* denormalize the schema to accommodate it. Instead, use unmapped properties in the entity for the latest post, or better, rely on projection to retrieve this data when it's needed. In both cases you would remove the LatestPostId from the User table

Unmapped property:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
    [NotMapped]
    public Post LatestPost 
    {
        get { return Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostedAt).FirstOrDefault(); }
    }
}
```

The caveat of the unmapped property approach is that you need to remember to eager-load Posts on the User if you want to access this property, otherwise you will trip a lazy load. You also cannot use this property in Linq expressions that get sent to EF (EF6) though they may work with EFCore, but risk performance issues if the expression gets translated to in-memory early. EF will not be able to translated LatestPost to SQL since there would be no key in the schema.

Projection:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}
```

Then if you want to retrieve a user and it's latest post:

```
var userAndPost = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .Select(x => new { User = x, LatestPost = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(PostedAt).FirstOrDefault()} ).Single();
```

Projection with `Select` can retrieve entities of interest, or better, simply return the fields from those entities into a flattened view model or DTO to send to UI or such. This results in more efficient queries against the database. Using `Select` to retrieve the details you don't need to worry about eager-loading via `Include`, and when done correctly, will avoid pitfalls with lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between User and Post is wrong. This should be your model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

That is one-to-many relationship: one user can have many posts and a post can have just one user.

Comment: this doesn't include last PostId in User model. As I said in the question, somehow I need to include last PostId in User model.

Comment: Why would you do that? That is unnecessary denormalization. You can retrieve last PostId from the collection of posts.

Comment: yes, that is some denormalization that i'm aware of. just for a bit of performance boost

Comment: @Reza: A Post ID in a User would imply that a user only has *1* post, as a User would only have 1 Post ID. While you can map EF to reference a single Post alongside a Posts collection, there is no way to reliably enforce *which* post that single Post refers to (first post? latest post?), or even if it refers to a Post in the Posts collection for that user. It's not so much a question of denormalization, but understanding the intended relationship of your data.

Comment: @StevePy, So in such situation I can't use `dbContext.Posts.Include(p=>p.User)` and should join them manually using `dbContext.Posts.Join(...)` ? I'm currently using Join(...)

Comment: You certainly can use `Include(p => p.User)`, For a Post to have a User does not require a User to have a singular Post, only that the Post table has a UserId. A user may, or may not have a Posts collection. A user can have many posts (0, 1, .. 100) A Post would require a single User. Post can reference it's user, and a User can optionally reference it's Posts. (plural)  By putting a singular Post ID in your User, you are confusing EF into thinking the relationship is 1-to-1. Perhaps expand your question to outline why you want to reference 1 singular Post from a User.

Comment: @StevePy, It is not about Post and User, I'm facing this problem for another scenario. In my scenario I have N to N relation that save some changes and one of this changes is assigned to the entity. I can put an active flag and toggle it but it would be good if there was some way to tell EF that I'm Including User from Post then UserId is the joining key not the PostId.

Answer (score 0):

You had enough of answers on this question  to how to create the model , I will just highlight what's wrong in your class

You have craete postid in user model as FK and therefore it will always consider it as relationship between user and post , you have to remove that and design it something similar to what is said by steve